# PHP html DOM vs pure HTML speed

Tags: php, html, performance, dom

It's a simple question, but which is faster between a simple html page with php echoing results or a html page build only by php dom ?

Thank you for your answers and your advices!

Comment: please be kind! It's a simple question

Comment: I don't see why people are downvoting (besides being a possible duplicate), this question should be useful for future reference.

Comment: Thank you Fabricio, i think too ^^

Answer (score 3):

Too many unknown variables …

When using DOM you can put much information very fast into your tree; using echo you need to track your (meta)data somehow else. To print a static page you should not use DOM. To print a page that is heavily modified during construction you would probably want to use DOM.

There is no right answer to this question. You need to do a benchmark for your specific usecase.

---

But you might value your time as well … I hope so. Even if it might be slower to render a page using DOM, it will be easier to let your project grow. Writing module systems that employ `echo` calls soon become a mess.

Comment: It will be a web application. The header will stay the same but content will change and sidebar too... I want clean code who will be easy to change with my page.class.php. How can i beanchmark the 2 pages to compare? Do you know if it will have a big impact? Thank you for your answer

Comment: Please see my update. But sorry, no I don't have actual measure data. But I have experience maintaining messy PHP code. ;-)

Comment: I'll make some test to night and i'll bring some feed back ^^

Comment: For a simple page with doctype,metas, title, it take 6ms and in pure html it take 3ms... But i'll continue the dom way to check how a big page is impacted

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing faster than plain HTML file being accessed directly. And best served with an **.html** extension.

PHP code has to go through the PHP interpreter, which is an additional step.

And this is the case for every server side language (C#, PHP, Python, Java, Node.js, etc)

Answer (score 1):

You should try some MVC Framework like Code Igniter

Wrting the same code again and again is not good.

You can split ur website like this

```
 ____________________________________
|                HEADER             |  // Header.php
|___________________________________| 
|                     NAV BAR       |  //menu.php
|___________________________________|
|                                   |  
|                                   |
|    Content                        | //Content {Different pages based on menu clicked}
|                                   |
|___________________________________|
|          FOOTER                   | 
|___________________________________|  //Footer.php
```

so All your pages will be like this

```
<?php
    include(header.php);
    include(menu.php);

    //based on menu clicked 
   include('clickedPage.php')

  //Finally
  include('footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: Some people told me thant codeignitier code isn't correct and i must don't touch this framework.... And the base question was not this. But ty for your advices